# Question about how burp suite repeater works

Tags: postman, burp

i have a request in burp which works fine with burp suite's repeater, but when i use the same request with postman, it somewhat doesnt work...?

I made sure that both requests are identical.

I dont really understand why this happens in burp, if anyone experienced in burp can you please explain how does burp repeaters work.
Here is some screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Servers are often protected by Cloudflare which makes TLS fingerprinting. Depending on the client software requests may pass the Cloudflare firewall or are rejected.